# AVCapturePhotoOutput : If you specify a non-nil format dictionary in your settings, your delegate must respond to the selector

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation

```
@IBAction func clickPicture(_ sender: UIButton) {

       let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        photoSettings.flashMode = .auto
        photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
        if photoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.count > 0 {
            photoSettings.previewPhotoFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : photoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!]
        }

        self.wideAngleOutPut.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)
    }
```

When i am calling above function to capture image app throwing exception on line: `self.wideAngleOutPut.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)`

In log section I can see the error in more details and its like:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** **-[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:] If you specify a non-nil format dictionary in your settings, your delegate must respond to the selector****

Can anybody help with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the following in your delegate if you set the previewPhotoFormat.

```
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?)
```

I'm guessing this is because this is the only way to access the preview in this situation.